# Why is $M_3$ embedded in any non-distributive lattice?

Tags: lattice-orders

I'm going through "Introduction to Lattices and Order" by Davey and Priestley (2nd ed.) and I'm struggling with a detail in the proof of the $M_3$-$N_5$ theorem. I understand every part of the proof except for one detail. In p. 91, in the proof that $u \wedge v = p$ I can't figure out how it goes from line 3 to 4. Reproducing these first four lines here:

\begin{align}
u \wedge v & = ((d \wedge q) \lor p) \wedge ((e \wedge q) \lor p) \\
           & = ((e \wedge q) \lor p) \wedge (d \wedge q)) \lor p)  & \textrm{by (M)} \\
           & = ((q \wedge (e \lor p)) \wedge (d \wedge q)) \lor p) & \textrm{by (M)} \\
           & = ((e \lor p) \wedge (d \wedge q)) \lor p             & \textrm{by ???} \\
           & = \cdots
\end{align}

It's the last one that I don't get. It requires that $q \wedge (e \lor p) = (e \lor p)$, but how? Certainly this would follow from the Connecting Lemma if we knew that $e \lor p \le q$, but I don't see how this is the case.

For reference, it is assumed that the lattice is modular but not distributive, and that  $(d \wedge e) \vee (d \wedge f) < d \wedge (e \vee f)$. And the following are defined:

\begin{align}
p & := (d \wedge e) \vee (e \wedge f) \vee (f \wedge d) \\
q & := (d \vee e) \wedge (e \vee f) \wedge (f \vee d) \\
u & := (d \wedge q) \vee p \\
v & := (e \wedge q) \vee p \\
w & := (f \wedge q) \vee p \\
\end{align}

I have tried a few things:

1. We know that $p \le q$, so it would be enough to show that $e \le q$ to obtain that $e \lor p \le q$, but how can we prove that $e \le q$?
2. Alternatively, since $q = \wedge \{d \vee e, e \vee f, f \vee d\}$, if we show that $e \vee p$ is a lower-bound of $\{ d \vee e, e \vee f, f \vee d \}$ then $e \lor p \le q$ would follow. But while it is easy to show that $e \vee p \le d \vee e$ and that $e \vee p \le e \vee f$, I don't see how to show that $e \vee p \le f \vee d$.

Comment: It doesn't. For example, $M_3$ doesn't embed into $N_5$. The proof is that if $L$ is modular but not distributive then $M_3$ embeds into $L$.

Comment: Concerning that specific line, it's just $q \wedge (d \wedge q) = d \wedge q$, after rearranging  the elements.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you! How could I miss that! It's a bit like chess blindness; forgetting to look at the other side.

Comment: And you are right, $M_3$ is not embedded in all non-distributed lattices. I was too hasty writing the question.